# Does the monero-powpy miner check if it has a new job?

Tags: mining, python

You can find it [here](https://github.com/jtgrassie/monero-powpy). I want to know if it checks if it has gotten another mining job while mining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stratum miner processes any jobs sent to it. Although the stratum miner is one file, it is actually two processes:

1. The main process handles the socket messages between itself and the connected pool.
2. A worker process which mines jobs.

Line [88](https://github.com/jtgrassie/monero-powpy/blob/6f312c887e0e84c188bef640cb22fd72cadd4ddf/stratum-miner.py#L88) (which is in the 1st process) has `q.put(job)`, which puts a received job in a queue and line [111](https://github.com/jtgrassie/monero-powpy/blob/6f312c887e0e84c188bef640cb22fd72cadd4ddf/stratum-miner.py#L111) (which is the 2nd process), has `job = q.get()`, which consumes a job and mines it.

Comment: Nice. Can you have it sys.stdout.write to the terminal when it gets a new job? Im too much of a noob to do that.

Comment: By the way, thanks for all the help you have been giving me :D

Comment: It already outputs to stdout when a new job is pulled from the queue. Line [123](https://github.com/jtgrassie/monero-powpy/blob/6f312c887e0e84c188bef640cb22fd72cadd4ddf/stratum-miner.py#L123).

Comment: Thznks! jjjjjjj

Comment: Can it tell when there is a new block?

Comment: You could monitor changes of height (line 118), but a stratum miner doesn't need to know when new blocks are mined to the main chain. Their job is simply to mine the block given by the pool and submit the result back.